# Getting deadlock inside match of async function

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, deadlock

I'm getting a deadlock on the following example:

```
use tokio::net::TcpListener;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use futures::lock::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct A{
    
}

impl A {
    pub async fn do_something(&self) -> std::result::Result<(), ()>{
        Err(())
    }
}

async fn lock_and_use(a: Arc<Mutex<A>>) {
    match a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await {
        Ok(()) => {
            
        },
        Err(()) => {
            //try again on error
            println!("trying again");
            a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await.unwrap();
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    println!("begin");
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(A{}));
    lock_and_use(a.clone()).await;
    println!("end");
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=040f75ac71fc30fb300bc102b3709946)

If I did this:

```
a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await;
a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await;
```

there would be no problem, the `lock()` dies on the same line it's created. I thought this principle would be the same for `match`. If you think about match, it locks the value, calls `do_something`, `await`s on it, and then compares the value. It's true that `do_something` returns a future which capture the `self`, but when we `await` on it, it should discard the `self`. Why it still holds `self`? How can I solve this without cloning the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

> Temporaries live for the entire statement, never shorter.

Cause code could be:

```rust
{
    match self.cache.read() { // <-- direct pattern matching
        Ok(ref data) => Some(data)
        _ => None,
    }
}.map(|data| {
    // use `data` - the lock better be held
})
```

Read [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37612) for more detail.

So you need to lock outside your match statement:

```rust
let x = a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await;
match x {
    Ok(()) => {}
    Err(()) => {
        a.clone().lock().await.do_something().await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this still deadlocks: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f564aa95095ddc0e6fc8889456613430

Comment: @Gatonito no it doesn't "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ()', src/main.rs:25:57" ? you make me loose 10 minutes xd